# Does smooth transitions faster than you can consciously perceive improve the user experience?

Tags: chrome, transitions, transparency

Google Chrome shows a smooth transition when you type something in its omnibar. It consists of a few frames of a diffuse glass-like autocomplete box before it becomes totally opaque.

It's faster than I can consciously perceive, I only noticed it because my computer froze at the right instant.

I wonder if those faster-than-the-eye improvements can be really perceived at some unconscious level.

Comment: maybe it's something that is displayed only when the computer is slow enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its faster than the eye can see then I doubt we will be able to appreciate on an unconscious level. I think that transition is there as a backup for when systems are performing slower than normal and the user needs to be informed that a process/action is taking place.

Comment: This is why we have these transitions, personally. It allows us to indicate to users with slower machines that the system is still working, albeit slowly.

Comment: Faster than the eye can see, and fast enough that you don't consciously notice the effect are certainly NOT the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

As you mentioned its about the subconscious level, if the system or application can provide  a perception that a system has changed state in a high speed that it almost seems instantaneous, it enhances the user experience since it gives a sense of continuity and also informs the user about the change.

To quote this [article](http://uxdesign.smashingmagazine.com/2012/02/28/mission-transition/) from smashing magazine

> A good transition should be almost invisible to the user. It should
>   help the user understand where they are navigating to and where they
>   have come from, but it should also be smooth and quick. A stall or
>   stutter impairs the overall user experience and tells the user that
>   something is wrong. There is such a thing as UI motion sickness, where
>   the user gets so used to the fluidity of moving between screens that
>   when a screen freezes for a second or two, the user feels like they’ve
>   come to a sudden stop. It is these sensations we should avoid.